# Warning: It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I've integrated Firebase into my React.js app as such:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

fire.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {
  apiKey: "####",
  authDomain: "#",
  databaseURL: "#",
  projectId: "#",
  storageBucket: "#",
  messagingSenderId: "#"
};
var fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default fire;
```

App.js:

```
import fire from './fire';

class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        let messagesRef = fire.database().ref('messages').orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting this warning in the console:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS
>   SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to
>   only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
>   (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database,
>   etc):
>
> CommonJS Modules: const firebase = require('firebase/app');
>   require('firebase/');
>
> ES Modules: import firebase from 'firebase/app'; 
>   import 'firebase/';

How do I fix this warning?

I have tried (in fire.js) changing this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

To this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

That results in this error:
[image]

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The proper way to import firebase is as such:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database'; // If using Firebase database
import 'firebase/storage';  // If using Firebase storage
```

Comment: Should the warning go away when I change my imports to this? I've changed it but still getting the warning.

Comment: @vhflat The warning went away for me, after I fixed the import statements in all of my project files.

Answer (score 81):

The proper way to import firebase and getting rid of the warnings is:

Always import this way

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Then import each sub-modules (each firebase service) as needed

```
import 'firebase/auth';        // for authentication
import 'firebase/storage';     // for storage
import 'firebase/database';    // for realtime database
import 'firebase/firestore';   // for cloud firestore
import 'firebase/messaging';   // for cloud messaging
import 'firebase/functions';   // for cloud functions
```

Comment: In what is your answer different from the already accepted one?

Comment: How about initializeApp ?

Comment: @toti08 it adds the import paths for firebase's other sub-modules, which is useful for people getting this same error with other firebase services.

Comment: What a great answer!

Comment: The app that I've been made to work on is getting this incessant warning, too. Is there a list of all the sub-modules somewhere so I can include all of them? I just want to get rid of the dumb warning.

Comment: Use `import 'firebase/installations';` for initializeApp

Answer (score 22):

The warning is rather informative and lays out exactly what you need to do. In your case, this is the line thats telling you to switch up the way you are importing your files:

> ES Modules: import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import 'firebase/';

In your `fire.js` file try changing this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

To this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

That should clear it up!

## **Side note:**

In my case I was using `firestore` so I had an additional import that I also changed from:

```
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
```

To:

```
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

Comment: I have tried this but it results in the error above (see modified question with attached image). Any ideas?

Comment: I found the solution

Comment: In the end, what was syntax of the imports?

Comment: See my answer to my question

Answer (score 2):

Something to note:

I am using firebase only for storage, but I still needed to:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/storage"
import "firebase/auth"
```

to avoid the webpack error in the OP.

I was authenticating the user prior to accessing the storage. Although I am not using firebase as my main auth provider.

Answer (score 0):

the same to me. I solved it in this way.

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
```

I used it in every place where I was importing Firebase in my project. This worked for me.

Of course, remember to use the services what you need in your Firebase initialization.

```
import 'firebase/auth';    
import 'firebase/storage';    
import 'firebase/database';   
import 'firebase/firestore';  
import 'firebase/messaging';  
import 'firebase/functions';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = app.auth();
const db = app.firestore();





----------------------------------

    import firebase from "firebase/app";
    import 'firebase/firestore';
    import 'firebase/auth';
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
      authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
      databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
      projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
      appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
      measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
    };
    
    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = app.auth();
    const db = app.firestore();
```

I try "/app+/< package >" and it works, and I display more code than above. At last, thanks above.