# How to stop the warning: It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-<PACKAGE>.js
```

**It takes half of my already limited console space :(**

**Note:** I use firebase inside html .. with script tags. I don't use import syntax as explained here : [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707211/warning-it-looks-like-youre-using-the-development-build-of-the-firebase-js-sdk)

How to stop this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error message tells you how to fix it... this part right here:

```
For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-<PACKAGE>.js
```

So if you're using Firebase authentication you'd have a script tag requesting `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-auth.js` ... and for the Firebase database you would also have another script tag with `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-database.js` .... just following that pattern for any other portions of Firebase you need.

Comment: i copy pasted the hole `firebase.js` source form the cdn and put it into my project to prevent too many requests over the network during development. Same with firestore.. i tried using only `../firebase-firestore.js` but i'm getting an error saing ii need to import the big library.. which in turn makes the `firestore` import worthless.. and produces this warning that you see. It might work with auth and the other ones. I'm gonna test it out again tomorrow.

Comment: they do have 2 imports in the documentation which makes things not clear in my opinion : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: Ah ha! Yeah, that's a contradictory piece of documentation. Check out this link instead: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup You'll need to include the "app" component.

Comment: yes it makes sense now .. i'm gonna download the `fireabase-app.js` from the cdn and put it in my project.

Comment: I had to link to the firebase-app.js as well: 

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.0/firebase-app.js"></script> 

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.0/firebase-database.js"></script>`

Answer (score 13):

To answer this question a little more clearly,

What you most likely have is

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
```

Because this is what Firebase gives you from the "Add Firebase to your web app" screen.

However, what this is doing is importing all of the Firebase modules. I don't know why Firebase has this as the generated script, but all you need to do is add -app to the source so it is now.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

Then with every subsequent feature of Firebase you would like to use, you would will need to add another script line. For example, if you would like to add cloud messaging to your web app it would only need.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

You can find more information including a complete list of imports [here from Firebase.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0)

Answer (score 0):

The details given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) are not super easy to understand:

step 1: Remove below line, because it's development build:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase.js"></script>
```

step 2: Add below line, (required), production build:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

step 3: Add any more packages/sevices you need, like database, (optional), production build:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

This solved the issue.

Comment: This is basicly the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51937415/4916627).

Comment: @andr%c3%a9-kool    Where did the word `production` exist in the answer?, Is it not too long for your time spent to read and understand? Why waste a lot of time for others? I don't mind the downvote, I will retain the answer for others good.