# Dev Build of Firebase JS SDK after updating imports

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've been trying to silence the warning:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS
> SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to
> only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
> (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database,
> etc):
>
> https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js

Per the instructions here [Warning: It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707211/warning-it-looks-like-youre-using-the-development-build-of-the-firebase-js-sdk), I've updated all of my imports to match this format but the warning is not silenced:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

I've searched my code for all instances of `from "firebase"` and cannot find any that haven't been updated to `from "firebase/app"`, so am a bit stumped. Are there any other imports that could be causing this? Here are my firebase packages in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.2.5",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.20.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^10.2.1",
    "firebaseui": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-firebaseui": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3",
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firebase-admin and firebase-functions modules are not for use in frontend web apps.  They are for backend nodejs code only.  You should remove them from this project.