# It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to integrate firebase with ReactJs like this.

Here is my code

```
import firebase from "firebase";



var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "", // Add API Key
  databaseURL: "" // Add databaseURL
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = firebase;

var firepadRef = firebase.database().ref();


export const userName = localStorage.getItem('auth_name');
const urlparams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const roomId = urlparams.get("id");

if (roomId) {
  firepadRef = firepadRef.child(roomId);
} else {
  firepadRef = firepadRef.push();
}

export default firepadRef;
```

And now I get this warning:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS
> SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to
> only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
> (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database,
> etc):
>
> CommonJS Modules: const firebase = require('firebase/app');
> require('firebase/');
>
> ES Modules: import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import
> 'firebase/';
>
> Typescript: import firebase from 'firebase

Comment: What have you tried? The error provides some suggestions, why aren't they working for you?

Comment: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707211/warning-it-looks-like-youre-using-the-development-build-of-the-firebase-js-sdk)

Comment: @subodhkalika I have changed this according to similar question you provided but still getting the warning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707211/warning-it-looks-like-youre-using-the-development-build-of-the-firebase-js-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

After a new firebase.initializeApp, (assuming you are using v9 of firebase), you need to instantiate the db differently. Check your docs. I'd write your code like this instead:

```
// firebase file which you export the initialization
import firebase from "firebase";



var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "", // Add API Key
  databaseURL: "" // Add databaseURL
};

// Initialize Firebase
var fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export fire.

//second js file
import firebase from ./firebase.js
import {getDatabase, ref, set} from "firebase/database";

var db = getDatabase(Firebase);

export const userName = localStorage.getItem('auth_name');
const urlparams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const roomId = urlparams.get("id");

//if you want to push to the db or something, you call the method
set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });

//more code here
```

All in all check the docs one more time. and use version 9, its implementation is the best.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_1

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import { child, getDatabase, push, ref } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "", // Add API Key
    databaseURL: "" // Add databaseURL
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getDatabase(app);

var firepadRef = ref(db);

export const userName = prompt("What's your name?");
const urlparams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const roomId = urlparams.get("id");

if (roomId) {
    firepadRef = child(firepadRef, roomId);
} else {
    firepadRef = push(firepadRef);
    window.history.replaceState(null, "Meet", "?id=" + firepadRef.key);
}

export default firepadRef;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).